# Knockout binding for radio button not working initially

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I currently have the following HTML...

```html
<input type="radio" style="height: 12px; width: 20px;" name="physTabPregRadio" value="true" data-bind="checked: pregnant.radioBool" />Y
<input type="radio" style="height: 12px; width: 20px;" name="physTabPregRadio" value="false" data-bind="checked: pregnant.radioBool" />N
<span data-bind="text: pregnant.radioBool" />
```

...and the `radioBool` function is an extension of ko, as defined here...

```
ko.observable.radioBool = function () {
    var observable = ko.observable();
    observable.radioBool = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (observable() === true) return 'true';
            else if (observable() === false) return 'false';
            else return 'unknown';
        },
        write: function (v) {
            if (v.toLowerCase() === 'true') observable(true);
            else if (v.toLowerCase() === 'false') observable(false);
            else observable(undefined);
        }
    });
    return observable;
};
```

...and is initialized in the model like this...

```
self.pregnant = ko.observable.radioBool();
self.pregnant(false);
```

Upon loading the page, neither radio button is checked, but the span's text is "false". Is there any potential reasons why the Radio Button would not be checked, even though its value is equal to one of the radio button's values?

Comment: Could you create a working example of this? [I failed to reproduce it.](https://jsfiddle.net/hp8jter2/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this approach?

Comment: @MikeC I think you'd need to use the radioBool. Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hp8jter2/1/

Comment: @MikeC: pregnant: ko.observable.radioBool()

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `var observable = ko.observable(false);` (with `false` explicitly), or else it'll have `undefined` as its value at first and consequently the `read` funciton will fall through to the final `else`.

See this example:

```js
var self = {};

ko.observable.radioBool = function () {
    var observable = ko.observable(false);
    observable.radioBool = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (observable() === true) return 'true';
            else if (observable() === false) return 'false';
            else return 'unknown';
        },
        write: function (v) {
            if (v.toLowerCase() === 'true') observable(true);
            else if (v.toLowerCase() === 'false') observable(false);
            else observable(undefined);
        }
    });
    return observable;
};

self.pregnant = ko.observable.radioBool();

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="physTabPregRadio" value="true" data-bind="checked: pregnant.radioBool" />Y
<input type="radio" name="physTabPregRadio" value="false" data-bind="checked: pregnant.radioBool" />N
<span data-bind="text: pregnant.radioBool" />
```

Comment: I probably should have specified that I set self.pregnant(false) later on. Note, I did say that the span's text value WAS returning the correct string value.

Comment: *Then your question doesn't contain (enough information to create) a repro*, I'm afraid. Try using the Stack Snippet feature you can see in my answer (it's on the editor's toolbar) to add a runnable repro to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Solved it by initializing the observable with a string value instead of a boolean or number.

```
self.pregnant('false');
```